# ping -a not resolving hostname for one host on Windows 7 client

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-7, ping

`ping -a 192.168.99.3` does not resolve hostname for `vcl.nailit.lab`, but does for other hosts  on network like `pfsense.nailit.lab`.

`nslookup vcl.nailit.lab` and `ping vcl.nailit.lab` work correctly. See output:

```
C:\Users\Administrator.NAILIT>ping -a 192.168.99.3

Pinging 192.168.99.3 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.99.3: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.99.3:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

C:\Users\Administrator.NAILIT>ping vcl.nailit.lab

Pinging vcl.nailit.lab [192.168.99.3] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.99.3: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.99.3:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms


C:\Users\Administrator.NAILIT>nslookup vcl.nailit.lab
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.99.13

Name:    vcl.nailit.lab
Address:  192.168.99.3

C:\Users\Administrator.NAILIT>ping -a 192.168.99.1

Pinging pfsense.nailit.lab [192.168.99.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.99.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.99.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms**
```

DNS records seem ok - identical for pfsense and vcl. DNS is on MS Server 2012

How exactly does ping -a resolve the host name? Why is everything except 'ping -a 192.168.99.3' work correctly?

Comment: Why is this important? Name resolution obviously works as evidenced by your nslookup and ping by name test. Are you simply curious as to the mechanism of ping -a and why it isn't resolving the name?

Answer (score 3):

> How exactly does ping -a resolve the host name?

This is called reverse DNS. Forward DNS resolves names into IP addresses. Reverse DNS resolves IP addresses into names. When you type `ping -a 1.2.3.4` into your computer, it issues the DNS query `PTR 4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa`. PTR stands for pointer record.

> Why is everything except 'ping -a 192.168.99.3' work correctly?

My instinct tells me that you are missing a PTR record for that IP address. On your DNS server, you should see what is called a Reverse Lookup Zone like `168.192.in-addr.arpa`. In there should lie the PTR records for all devices on that network.  Windows devices usually attempt to register their own forward and reverse DNS records, but they cannot do so if the entire reverse lookup zone is missing.